# Yii2: how to install multi-input widget

Tags: php, yii2

i have been trying to use this [**`yii2-multiple-input`**](https://github.com/unclead/yii2-multiple-input/) widget but can't seem to be working. I have put the downloaded folder inside the vendor dir.

> Error : Class 'unclead\multipleinput\MultipleInput' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way to install this extension is through [**`composer`**](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx).

Either run

```
php composer.phar require  unclead/yii2-multiple-input "~2.0"
```

or add

```
"unclead/yii2-multiple-input": "~2.0"
```

to the require section of your `composer.json` file.

Comment: Thanks alot ! \m/